# How to check a DateTime is an occurence of recurring event using Joda Time?

Tags: java, performance, time, jodatime

I've a `DateTime` that represent the beginning of a recurring event.  A `Days` (daily period) will represent the recurring period.  I assume that this recurring event will never stop.

```
from = "2013-06-27"  
period = 3 days
nextOccurence will be "2013-06-30", "2013-07-03", "2013-07-06", and so on.
"2013-07-03" is an occurence but "2013-07-04" isn't an occurence.
```

I would like to know what is the best way in term of performance to determine if a `DateTime` is an occurence of the recurring event? In the long term, the program will need to check if "2014-07-03" or "2015-07-03" is an occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs all five checks in 180 ms seconds on my machine.  Or about 27-checks/second, where you are checking a date 300 years in the future.

```
@Test
public void isOccurrence() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    assertTrue(isOccurrence(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 10), 3, new DateTime(2010, 1, 19, 0, 0)));
    assertFalse(isOccurrence(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 10), 3, new DateTime(2010, 1, 18, 0, 0)));

    assertTrue(isOccurrence(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 10), 3, new DateTime(2310, 1, 19, 0, 0)));
    assertFalse(isOccurrence(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 10), 3, new DateTime(2310, 1, 20, 0, 0)));

    assertTrue(isOccurrence(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 10), 3, new DateTime(2010, 1, 10, 0, 0)));

    System.out.println("elapsed=" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
}

public boolean isOccurrence(DateMidnight startDate, int dayIncrement, DateTime testTime) {
    DateMidnight testDateMidnight = testTime.toDateMidnight();
    while (startDate.isBefore(testDateMidnight)) {
        startDate = startDate.plusDays(dayIncrement);
    }
    return startDate.equals(testDateMidnight);
}
```

Comment: You've saved me from premature optimization! I've been thinking about redesigning my classes, but I now know it is not worthy. Thank you for the fact!

Comment: @Keith By the way, all the "midnight"-related classes and methods in Joda-Time have been deprecated. Use the newer [`DateTime::withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method instead. But this issue does not affect the logic of this Answer. Or would `LocalDate` be appropriate here?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `add` method in the `Calendar` class.

You could do the following -

```
Date date = "2013-06-27" ; 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(date);  
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3); // add 3 days  
date = cal.getTime();
```

And so on...

Comment: If I'm checking for a date in 2015 or 2017, it will be a lot of looping. Will that create performance issue or it is negligible?

Comment: You cannot do anything more than this. There is `DateUtils` but it does not let you define 3 days but week or month which gives out an iterator.

Comment: I see that this is the only possible solution. I will wait for more feedback before accepting your answer.  Thanks.